# Semantic-UI-React Responsive component renders element in spite of minWidth/maxWidth prop

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantics, semantic-ui-react

I have a component where I want to render different components based on screen size. If I reload the page while on mobile view, everything is ok, NavBarMobile is rendered and NavbarDesktop is not.

If I reload the page while on desktop view,  then my NavbarMobile is rendered again instead of NavBarDesktop.

If I start resizing the screen to mobile and back to desktop view, NavBarDesktop is rendered correctly.

So, the problem is first page load while in Desktop view, how to fix that?

```
 const { mainAppComponents, } = this.props
    const { visible, } = this.state
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Responsive maxWidth={767}>
          <NavBarMobile
            onPusherClick={this.handlePusher}
            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
            rightItems={rightItems}
            visible={visible}
          >
            {mainAppComponents.header}
            {mainAppComponents.routes}
          </NavBarMobile>
        </Responsive>

        <Responsive minWidth={768}>
          <NavBarDesktop rightItems={rightItems}>{mainAppComponents.header}</NavBarDesktop>
          {mainAppComponents.routes}
        </Responsive>
      </Fragment>
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Igor-Vuk, I put together a quick codesandbox example just to make sure there was not a problem with how you are trying to implement the min/max width props. As you can see from this example, they do in fact work as expected. https://codesandbox.io/s/98pk46l7vr

Without seeing the rest of your component, or application, the issue may be due to something in your router. I'd recommend trying to remove some of the other components you are returning as children of the `Responsive` component to see if it starts working as expected (like in my codesandbox example). If it works, then you know the problem is somewhere in the children. If it does not work then there is a greater problem above in your app.

If you are using SSR, on initial load the content was rendered and served with the `Responsive` component having no knowledge of the viewport. So you may need to also add a CSS media query.

Comment: Thanks brianespinosa.I think I know what’s the problem but I am not sure how to fix it. The error is happening only when I use server-side rendering.Since my code is split into few bundles,  bundle.js and separate bundle for css and so on it takes longer time for CSS bundle to be downloaded then bundle.js.Maybe server side rendering doesn't take into account this maxWidth and minWidth since it doesn't yet know what to do with it. Then when everything is downloaded it just fills the stuff  that SSR prepared. If I start to change screen size at this point everything works. Just not first render.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. SSR would definitely cause that. The `Responsive` component needs to know what the viewport/window width is. In the case of SSR it doesn't know. So both should be rendering in this case until your viewport size changes.

Basically the `Responsive` component is not what I'd recommend for the case of SSR unless you are also coupling those components with CSS media queries. If you use media queries instead (or alongside) of the `Responsive` component, this should work.

Comment: Thanks brianespinosa. You explained it much nicer then me. Yes, I tried it. I removed the max/minWidth and put the regular css classes paired with media queries. It works now. So I should not use ```Responsive``` at all with SSR? Is there any benefit in using ```Responsive``` as a wrapper in my example without max/minWidth but regular css class or should I put just regular <div>? Also if I use media queries instead, but my css bundle is still taking a longer time then bundle.js to download will I have the same problem. Have a little problem testing it now.

Comment: Basically the `Responsive` component and media queries are doing two different things. With media queries, the markup will still be in the DOM and those components get rendered. You can just elect to not have them show in the DOM with the query. With `Responsive` it is actually selectively rendering/not rendering the children based on the configuration.

There are benefits to both solutions and also for combining them. You need to decide what is right for your use case. :) Also, if the answer above was helpful, consider marking it as the selected solution.

Comment: Yes, I did some testing. With Queries both component were rendered server side but it was displayed correctly in browser. If I added Responsive and queries together it did not work again. Adding just Responsive did not work also. Why is that combination of Responsive and Queries did not work?
Yes, thank you, your answer was very helpfull. I will accept it, can you please just explain this last question since you seem familiar with semantic-ui-react.

Comment: I would have to see what your media queries were. The `Responsive` component is probably not working with SSR because it's still never going to know the viewport size so it does not know which to render. I would only use the `Responsive` component if you are not doing SSR. Basically that component is only going to work well for client rendered apps. To work in your situation it would need some additional features to  let you tell it what to render if SSR is happening. Or to be able to pass a viewport width if none is detected. Then you could do user agent detection on the server and guess it.

Comment: I know this is an older question but I wanted to mention there's now a way to address `Responsive` elements when using SSR. It's not well documented but [this issue from the Semantic UI repo](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3110#issuecomment-427307453) shows how. If you add a `fireOnMount` property to the component and add a call to `getWidth` as shown to detect when you're in a browser context vs. not, your `Responsive` elements will work properly.